# How are the unit/counit of a Hopf algebra and of an categorical adjunction related?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, terminology, hopf-algebras, adjoint-functors

For categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$, a pair of functors $\mathcal{C} \xrightarrow{\;L\;} \mathcal{D}$ and $\mathcal{C} \xleftarrow{\;R\;} \mathcal{D}\,$ are an [adjoint pair](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjunction) if we have natural transformations $\eta \colon 1_\mathcal{C} \Rightarrow RL$ and $\varepsilon \colon LR \Rightarrow 1_\mathcal{D}$, called the *unit* and *counit* respectively, that satisfy the [triangle identities](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/triangle+identities).

On the other hand, a [Hopf algebra](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hopf+algebra#definition) $H$ is an associative and coassociative bialgebra equipped with a multiplication $\nabla$, a comultiplication $\Delta$, an antipode $S$, and *unit* and *counit* maps $\eta$ and $\varepsilon$ such that $\nabla \circ (1_H \otimes S) \circ \Delta = \Delta \circ (S \otimes 1_H) \circ \nabla = \eta\circ \varepsilon$.

How are these two different definitions of *unit*/*counit* related? I mean, I know they must be the same idea when viewed in the right context, but I haven't figured it out yet, and neither nLab nor [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_algebra#Formal_definition) spells it out. I'm sure I could figure this out myself eventually and type up an nice answer (and will if no one else feels like typing it up), but I'll bet someone on this site already knows the relationship well and can provide some useful insight too.

Comment: How do you know that they must be the same idea?

Comment: I don't think they're closely related.  The unit/counit of a Frobenius algebra, on the other hand, is somewhat related to adjunctions because LR is a Frobenius monad when L and R are biadjoint.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Gut feeling? Maybe Noah is right and there isn't much of a relationship here.

Comment: There is a general notion of algebra or coalgebra object in a monoidal categeory. Algebras have units (at least the unital ones do) and coalgebras have counits. A Hopf algebra is both an algebra and a coalgebra object in vector spaces. On the other hand, an adunction gives rise to a monad (and a comonad) which are (co)algebra objects in a category of endofunctors - the (co)unit mentioned above is part of this structure. So in this sense they are both examples of a more general notion. I'm not sure if there is anything much deeper than that though.

Comment: Plus mentioning that you can make a Hopf monad too.

Comment: Right, there is such a thing as a Hopf monad, but they don't have anything to do with adjoint functors.  Biadjoint functors give a Frobenius monad but *not* a Hopf monad.